# Is anyone else is having issue using Java 8 with Android Studio 3.0?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

**I have issue with Java 8 when I use**

```
 compileOptions {
                sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
                targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            }
```

**I Get Error**

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug'. > 
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java 
process with main class
```

Comment: There are a whole range of reports of problems with "transformClassesWithDesugarForDebug", though none that closely matches your error message.  Try googling.  (And the answer to your question is "yes")

Answer (score 2):

Just update your build tools . It should be solved in build tools 3.0.0-beta4 .